# Tricking audio autoplay using iframe in javascript for Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have written a javascript code to generate iframe and hide the frame, to autoplay audio in Chrome browser. The code is below,

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:audio/mpeg;base64,/+MYxAAAAANIAAAAAExBTUUzLjEwMF';
iframe.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Also, the audio autoplays automatically.

Is it possible to play audio in Chrome without iframe? I found a [javascript](https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js) in [Muses Radio Player](https://muses.org/) which autoplays audio in Chrome.

I am not expert in javascript. Can anybody find the secret in the [javascript](https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js)?